# Android SwitchCompat not rendering track when in off state

Tags: android, switchcompat

My question is probably best asked visually -- I want a [`SwitchCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) switch to look the way they do in the Android Settings app:

This is off:

[image]

This is on:

[image]

But for some reason, my `SwitchCompat` switch looks like this when off:

[image]

There is no gray "track" extending out to the right side. But, when on, it looks as expected:

[image]

As you can see I have applied a custom tint to my application. My custom tint was applied as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".editor.MySettingsEditor"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" />
```

And then, in styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">    
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myColorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

To ensure it was not my custom styling causing this issue, I removed it by doing this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".editor.MySettingsEditor"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
```

But still, the "off" track does not display, though the tint color now goes to the Android default teal.

[image]
[image]

Why is my `SwitchCompat` switch missing the grey track when in the off state?

The XML that describes the SwitchCompat is super-simple:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you disable that custom tint, does your track return?

Comment: How exactly have you 'applied a custom tint'? Aren't you just using your theme's `colorControlActivated`?

Comment: I have added more details to my question describing exactly how I am doing my color/theme customization in this Activity. LMK if there is any more detail I can or should provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply custom tint by setting `colorControlActivated` for active color and `colorSwitchThumbNormal` for inactive color. If you want to change track color then you can set `android:colorForeground`

```
<style name="CustomSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat">  
    <!-- active thumb-->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/active_switch_color</item>

    <!-- inactive thumb-->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/inactive_switch_color</item>

    <!-- inactive track color -->
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/inactive_track_color</item>
</style>
```

In case you want to set custom theme directly to your view:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/CustomSwitch"/>
```

Comment: That was it! I had a dark theme applied and so I think the track color was being set to white, though in this particular view I was rendering the switch against a white background so the track color was white-on-white, thus invisible.

Comment: I was missing `android:colorForeground`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@esilver Perhaps a better way if you want to handle them Dynamically

Try this... I have tested and it is working perfectly fine

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked},
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked},
    };

    int[] thumbColors = new int[] {
            Color.BLACK,
            Color.RED,
    };

    int[] trackColors = new int[] {
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.BLUE,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch);
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(switchCompat.getThumbDrawable()), new ColorStateList(states, thumbColors));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(switchCompat.getTrackDrawable()), new ColorStateList(states, trackColors));
    }
}
```

You will only need to update the "trackColors" and the "thumbColor" as per you requirement/needs.